# Batch limit of 5 on Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

When trying to create a deamon application for mass updating users calendars, I stumbled upon the following documentation:

- [Issues with JSON batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#json-batching)
- [JSON batching new API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching)
- [Batching Outlook REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/batch-outlook-rest-requests)

As it seems you can batch (aka combine) up to 20 requests in the "don't use this API for new project API", but you can only combine up to 5 requests with the new Microsoft Graph API.

I found that without batching creating and deleting 100 calendar items takes around 40 seconds. Since application management got so much easier I want to use the new API, but is there any change the 5 request batch limit will be removed to let's say 20 like on the old API?

Comment: I think this question have no relation with the `batch-file` tag, so I suggest you to remove it. You may review the description of such a tag hovering the mouse over it.

Comment: Ok removed the wrong placed tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The batching feature is currently in beta. The limitation of 5 requests in the batch is a limitation I hope will be very short-lived. Customer asks will help me to advocate for that to happen. I've created a uservoice ask for this change here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19505020-raise-or-remove-the-limit-on-number-of-requests-al. Voting on this ask will help demonstrate that the limitation should indeed be modified.

Comment: Thanks for creating a service request to remove the limit. If everyone facing issues with the limit could please up the user voice...

Comment: Quick Update: [JSON Batching was released to GA](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog) in January 2018 and now supports up to 20 requests.

Comment: I've tried this using 6 requests and it works. So this answer can be outdated. Can you please update this answer with more current information? PS1: The link you've provided doesn't exists anymore. PS2: Is it possible to batch batch requests?